# DJango how to write a view.py for signing in and registering as well as a log out

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hi I am new to Django I just want to know how to write the POST and GET so I can sign in and log out as well as register?
 thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Have you tried working through some Django tutorials?

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks guys for writing in I have viewed most of those sources before but still struggling, I will figure things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the official tutorial here at 
[Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/). This is highly detailed documentation and you might rarely run into problem if you follow what they say. Please post questions that show some research.

Comment: My bad I have done extensive research but I am still struggling but this looks like a good start to my solution so thanks for writing in I appreciate it :).